# Finding Lebesgue measure using Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $E$ be Lebesgue measurable and

$$E_f = \{(x,y,z + f(x,y)) :
(x,y,z) \in E\}.$$

Show that $m_3(E) = m_3(E_f)$ directly from Fubini’s theorem, where $m_3$ is the $3$ dimensional Lebesgue measure.

**Attempt:**

\begin{align*}
&\iiint_{\{(x,y,z): (x,y,z)\in E+(0,0,f(x,y))\}\}} \, dxdydz \\
&=\int m_2(\{(x,y): (x,y,z)\in E-(0,0,f(x,y))\}\}) \, dz\\
&=\int_{\{z\mid (x,y,z)\} \in E} m_2(\{(x,y): (x,y,z)\in E\})\\
&=m_3(E)
\end{align*}

Comment: Note: Not using Fubini’s theorem, but it is well known and one of the primary motivations for Lebesgue’s measure that it is translation invariant on measurable sets.

Comment: @FShrike can you help me do this directly from Fubini's theorem? I honestly have no clue how to go about that.

Comment: @FShrike But this is not, strictly speaking, a translation, since $f(x,y)$ depends on $(x,y)$.  That is why we should apply Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @GEdgar can you help me with this? I am preparing for an exam with this.

Comment: @Jolie ... You should do it, no us.  $m_3(E_f)$ can be written as a triple integral in many different ways.  Find one of those ways so that translation invariance of $m_1$ can be used on it.

Comment: @GEdgar Can I write it as $\int \int \int z+f(x,y)dzdydx$? Can you help me write the triple integral correctly?

Comment: no, $m_3(E_f)$ will be a triple integral of the constant $1$ integrated on a certain domain.

Comment: @GEdgar would it be $\int_0^{x}\int_0^{y}\int_{0}^{z+f(x,y)}dzdydx$?

Comment: @GEdgar or would this be correct $\int\int\int_{E-\{(0,0,f(x,y))\}}dxdydz$? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: @GEdgar I think I have a correct solution now. Can you please verify it?

Comment: I can’t right now. If no one has answered it in an hour or so’s time I’ll have time to answer it. Follow the indication of @GEdgar in the meantime!

Comment: @FShrike thank you.

Comment: @FShrike when you get the time...Is it correct? Should the minus in the second set be a $+$?

Comment: I was just typing something out, but Matematleta has beaten me to it! Their answer is just fine. As for your proof, it's a bit hard to read. It's easier to say $(x,y,z-f(x,y))\in E$ than to say $(x,y,z)\in E-(0,0,f(x,y))$, and you are using Fubini but it is not explicit *how* you are using it. See the below answer for clarity. Strictly speaking, we use Fubini-Torelli here, as the characteristic function is positive and so it doesn't matter whether the quantity is integrable or not. If perhaps you had a situation with signed measures, the case $\mu_3(E)=\infty$ would make it more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Fubini, the translation-invariance of $m_1$ for each $\textit{fixed}\ (x,y),$ and the definitions of $E$ and $E_f,$  calculate (spoiler in the middle, if you get really stuck),

$\displaystyle m_3(E_f)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}\chi_{E_f}(x,y,z_1)dm_3(x,y,z_1)=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_{E_f}(x,y,z_1)dm(z_1)\right)dm_2(x,y)$

> $\displaystyle=\int_{\mathbb R^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_E(x,y,z+f(x,y))dm(z+f(x,y))\right)dm_2(x,y)$

$=\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb R^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_E(x,y,z)dm(z)\right)dm_2(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb R^3}\chi_E(x,y,z)dm_3(x,y,z)=m_3(E).$